# dbutils.notebook.run not working for mapping arguments

Tags: scala, databricks

Suppose I have 2 notebooks of which the first is the main and the second is for testing.

In the main, I have the following

```
dbutils.notebook.run("testing", timeoutSeconds = 60, arguments = Map("var" -> "1234"))
```

In testing:

```
%scala
println(s"Donut price = $var")
```

And in Main run the notebook. There is error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can pass arguments to DataImportNotebook and run different notebooks (DataCleaningNotebook or ErrorHandlingNotebook) based on the result from DataImportNotebook.

> val status = dbutils.notebook.run("DataImportNotebook", timeoutSeconds
>   = 60, argumenrs = Map ("x" -> "1234"))
>
> println("Status: " + status)

[image]

In scala, the variables are declared as follows:

The following are examples of value definitions:

> var $price = 1234
>   println("Donut price:" + $price)

[image]

For more details, refer "[Scala - How to declare variables](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-2-learning-basics-scala-programming/scala-basic-tutorial-declare-variables-types/)" and "[Databricks - Notebook workflows](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)".

Hope this helps.